# PHP - Catchable fatal error: Object of class could not be converted to string

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a simple select in PHP OOP:

```
public function loginUsuario($usuario)
{
    try {
        $pdo = Database::getConnectionPDO();

        $usuario = new Usuario();
        $usuario->setUsuario($usuario);

        $sql = ' SELECT nombres, apellidos FROM tb_usuario WHERE usuario=:usuario ';

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':usuario', $usuario->getUsuario(), PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $stmt->execute();
        $rs = $stmt->fetchAll();

        echo count($rs);

    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        throw $ex;
    }
}
```

But, when i run the method i have this error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class Usuario could not be converted to string in D:\xampp\htdocs\usuarios\core\model\usuarioModel.php on line 20
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: The object name and varible name are same.

Comment: Show us the error line from your model

Comment: Ohhh, It was the object name... thank you Tamil !

Answer (score 0):

The object name `$usuario` and variable name `$usuario` are same.

change a object name, it solves the problem